# Не запускается gulp в проекте

Tags: gulp

```
$ gulp
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\OSPanel\domains\store.loc\gulpfile.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Comment: Ну вот, вам же открытым текстом пишут Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'. Убедитесь в наличии данного модуля, и установите, если отсутствует.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогите, пожалуйста, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

Comment: большое спасибо